# Don't find <tr> nodes with findAll()

Tags: python

I have been trying to find all game ids on website: https://www.flashscore.com/football/germany/bundesliga/results

I want to get all ids with format g_1_nXU7hYul:

```
<tr id="g_1_nXU7hYul" class="odd stage-finished" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <td class="cell_ib icons left"></td>
    <td class="cell_ad time">31.03. 18:00</td>
    <td class="cell_ab team-home  bold" title="Click for match detail!">
        <span class="padr">Eintracht Frankfurt</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_ac team-away">
        <span class="padl">Stuttgart</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_sa score  bold">3&nbsp;:&nbsp;0</td>
    <td class="cell_ia icons">
        <span class="icons"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried the code beneath but the output is an error.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.flashscore.com/football/germany/bundesliga/results/"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("tr", {"class":"odd stage-finished"})
print(containers[0])
```

I expect all tr nodes but I dont find any node

Comment: The website is: https://www.flashscore.com/football/germany/bundesliga/results

Comment: There is no such `<tr>` in the page source, it must be loaded with Javascript from an API

Comment: I think there is knowledge missing on my side. When I click on "Inspect Element" at a specific game, I find this <tr> path.

Comment: yes you do - but it's been put there by Javascript. Right click and select "view source", and search for these classes - they're not there. And that HTML source is what BeautifulSoup gives you. It doesn't, and can't, run the JS. You need to find the API that site fetches the data from.

Comment: I dont have the api for this site, can I not just copy the html of "Inspect Elements" and readn that in? here I can see the <tr>s

Comment: `can I not just copy the html of "Inspect Elements" and readn that in?` How would you do that programatically? I don't think you can. They are obviously getting this data from some API, I've just spent a bit of time searching the JS source, as well as googling, and haven't been able to find the URL the API is served at yet - but it must exist somewhere.

Comment: If the API cannot be accessed programmatically for some reason (which seems unlikely, unless the Javascript is heavily obfuscated), another solution may be using a headless browser like Selenium (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load and build the page. This could allow Python to load and build the page like a normal browser would, including JS scripts.

Comment: You can use selenium to automate the clicking, then you can actually use Beautifulsoup to scrape the <tr> tags.

Comment: Ok thank you all, I will try it out now and tell you how it worked with selenium